# CSS Animation in React

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate my SPAN to increase decrease it's size. But It affects my other style. Please see video below

CSS

```
.textdiv {
animation: textgrowth 1s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@keyframes textgrowth {
  0% {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}
```

Login Page

```
<h1 className={classes.heading}>
          TEST{" "}
          <span
            className={"textdiv"}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#5D9CEC",
              color: "white",
              borderRadius: "8px",
              padding: "8px",
            }}
          >
            TESTING
          </span>
        </h1>
```

[image]

The problem is also my other elements are moving. I only want the Span or word TESTING to move big and small.

Comment: The other elements down below are moving because of the positon you set on all the elements. For example if you set the login form to absolute instead it wont move

Comment: It's easier to help with all the code

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to move the span itself, try adding a container element with 'position: relative;' and add 'position: absolute;' to the span itself. (+ something to fix the positioning)

```css
.textdiv {
position: absolute;
transform: translateY(-50%);
animation: textgrowth 1s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.container {
position: relative;
}

@keyframes textgrowth {
  0% {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}
```

```html
TEST <span class="container"><span class="textdiv">TESTING</span></span>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. it still moves my form

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because of the font size change if you fix  height to max value it will not move your other element.

```
h1{min-height:60px} /* Set the height so h1 height will not change after animation */
```

Comment: hello this is kinda working for me. But I only want the TESTING word to move.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: "Testing" is a child span of H1 and you don't need to do anything with "Testing" word(Keep it as you want).  Just set the height of H1